# Using Django-Rest-Framework is adding records via API when the API is readonly

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, restangular

I'm not sure where the problem is coming from but, here's what's happening.

I have a fairly complex object. It has several different FK and M2M relationships. When I'm creating a new object it builds the relationships and then adds the records. Including making NEW instances of the Child in the Child table, but the Child table is ReadOnly.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Here's my serializer:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(required=False, read_only=True, view_name='children-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'description')
```

Here's the View:

```
ChildViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoModelPermissions,)
```

What I want to happen is that the records from the DB are retrieved via the API and then, when a new parent object is created, the Child object is added to the parent.

Comment: Well each time you successfully post to that endpoint you're going to make a "Child" object because that's how you have it coded. It won't assign attributes to "children", but it'll still make the Child object because that's the model you assigned to that endpoint. Perhaps you want an endpoint based on Parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the API is ReadOnly, why would it allow me to post. I think I understand what you mean by "based on parent" do you have a reference that I could look at?

Comment: Well I can't see your full models, if you paste those it would help. But the "ChildViewSet" has in the class Meta "model = Child" and then you also add a field to that serializer yourself called "children". The field you added is read_only, but the rest of the models actual fields are still writable and when you post to that an instance is made. What you mean is to have a ParentSerializer with read only attribute of children.

Comment: AHHHH! Ok. That makes sense. I'll look deeper at that. Thanks stormlifter!